# What exactly happens when we change extension of a file?

Tags: windows, file

I opened a `.mp3` file in notepad and save it to `.txt`, then again I saved it back to `.mp3` by opening it again in notepad,but when I tried to run it, the player was unable to recognize the format. I did not understand what happened when I changed the extension as I did not change the data in the file.

Comment: Did you transmit (i.e. using FTP, version control, etc.) the file between machines while it had a .txt extension?

Comment: was the player able to recognize the format prior to you changing the extension? (that is, did you play that file before you changed it's extension to txt)?

Comment: I changed it back on the same machine.

Comment: @Martina yes the player was able to recognize the extension and was able to play it.

Answer (score 4):

The operation of changing the file extension on Windows should have no effect on the file itself. However, if you opened the file when it was a `.txt` (so it opened in `Notepad`), and then saved it — you may have corrupted the file.

Comment: I didnot changed the content of the file,just saved it again to .mp3 extension.

Comment: @user1781308 : unless you didn't mean exactly what you said, then you SAVED the file again as mp3, assuming from the TXT extension, assuming from something like Notepad - which WOULD HAVE changed your file as Notepad isn't able to handle non printable characters well which an mp3 file contains a lot of. That is your answer, you DID change the file by SAVING it again. Please note that "renaming a file" is something altogether different than "saving file as"

Comment: yes, i took a .mp3 file opened it in notepad,saved it as .txt,then again opened it in notepad and saved it as .mp3.

Comment: That's your issue - as @Martina says... when you saved the file as .txt, Notepad saved a 'corrupted' version of the MP3*, and so your player software could't play it. 

Sadly, there is no way to undo this. You'll need to go back to a backup or copy of the original file.

*Notepad is designed for text files, but MP3s are binary, so Notepad attempts to open it the best way it can - which is as text, which can't represent binary. So when you saved it, Notepad just saved the text version it generated, which isn't valid - and resulted in a corrupt file.

Comment: @Martina I understood what you said,but i was just wondering when i opened the .mp3 file in notepad and it was unable to handle the non printable characters,what happened to that binary data? as the size of both the .mp3 and .txt file were same i.e 4,847,451 bytes in both the files.

Comment: Use the `fc /b` command to see what changed.

Comment: 1. Google "How Are You?" 2. Translate the string into some foreign language like Hebrew, Arabic, etc. 3. Copy it to your notepad and SAVE. 4. Now again copy the same text from notepad and paste it back on Google to translate in English. Whoa, what happened? The same thing happened with your mp3.

Comment: @user1781308 Hi. Very simply put, Notepad will try to understand this music file (which is binary data) as some long letter. Because lots of the data isn't readable to human (and neither to Notepad) it will try to "fix" that file and will replace some of the most confusing characters by perhaps a **?** (for the sake of argument - it doesn't matter if it's not ? but * or !) so as to draw your attention to it (because it expects that you are about to read through it and REPAIR those "bad" letters manually). You instead saved the file with questionmarks thus corrupted the file keeping it's size.

Comment: @Martina Thanks,now i understood what happened to my .mp3 file.

Comment: @user1781308 You are quite welcome. :)